# How I do resolve this error while running Exodus cryptocurrency wallet on linux?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I downloaded the zip file from http://www.exodus.io/releases/. Then I unzipped it using:

```
unzip exodus-linux-x64-1.40.0.zip
```

But, when I try to run the program, that resides in the Exodus-linux-x64 directory, using:

```
./Exodus
```

It gives this error:

```
./Exodus: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how you installed this application. There are slightly different ways to answer this, which could be clarified by knowing that information.

Comment: Also, rather than checking for missing libraries one-at-a-time, use `ldd ./Exodus` to check all the needed libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install gconf2
```

seems to be the fix

Answer (score 0):

You need to install any dynamic dependencies the program needs. In the case of your question specifically you will need to install `libgconf-2-4` to get rid of that error. You may also need to install other libraries, which you can see by running `ldd Exodus` and looking for the ones labeled `not found`.